# How to hide parent product in Woo-commerce on shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently using Show Variations On Shop & Category WooCommerce plugin to display single variation products on the Shop page, however, I only want to display my variation product but not the parent product with them as it's just duplicating on the site. Is there any way to hide the parent product and display the only variation of products.

Comment: Of course. If you just want to visually hide it, then share your page or the relevant HTML snippet that you'd like to hide.

Comment: @emsoff Thank you for your quick response, well there is no workaround to hide the elements by targetting DOM because the products are in the loop and they don't have any specific ID's, I am using simple WordPress theme on my local machine, therefore, I don't have any live URL. :(

Comment: Most themes will add classes to parent products. If that's not the case, then it can be removed with a filter in functions.php. Can you post the relevant loop?

Comment: You were right, there is a class :D my bad thanks buddy really appreciate your help :)